# Set Image ImageButton Using Picasso

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, picasso, imagebutton

I need to set an image of an ImageButton to an image stored in Firebase.

I'm currently viewing the data in an EditText in this template:

```
nameCompanyDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Company").child(user_id).child("name_company");

mNameCompany = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNameCompany);


nameCompanyDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mNameCompany.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

How could I do to display a stored image.
I have the following bank details:

```
fotoCompanyDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Company").child(user_id).child("photo");

fotoCompanyDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        /* Set the image here */  
        /* I would like to use Picasso */              


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

Structure Picasso:
Class Example:
public void setImage(final Context c, final String image){

            final ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);

            /*Procedimento preparado para funcionar offline*/
            Picasso.with(c).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(post_image, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                    /*Processo para carregar e visualizar imagem - Ocorre quando estiver Online*/
                    Picasso.with(c).load(image).into(post_image);

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Any way to use this structure template to display the FireBox result in the ImageButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
String urlFoto =  dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
Picasso.with(this).load(urlFoto).into(mSelectImage);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use `Glide`, which i kindly recomand you. To achieve this, you can use the following code:

```
Glide.with(post_image.getContext())
    .load(profilePhotoUrl)
    .centerCrop().transform(newCircleTransform(post_image.getContext()))
    .override(40,40)
    .into(post_image);
```

Also don't forget to add this line of code in the dependencies of your build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes but how would I use the above nameCompanyDB structure described above? @AlexMamo

Comment: If you replace Picasso with Glihe, should work fine. Do you have an error?

Comment: Sorry, I could not I'm kind of lost in how to set the result in EditText. @AlexMamo

Comment: Try to move the declaration of the `EditText mNameCompany = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNameCompany);` inside the `onDataChange()` method.